# help me identify this novel from my childhood

Tags: story-identification

I remember a quote about "it's eye was bigger than alaska". It's about a monster dragon that was huge and constantly demanded to be fed

Comment: While the quote is very helpful, we can always use some more details. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details!

Comment: A wild guess, but possibly the second part of Ted Hughes's [*The iron Man*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Man_(novel)), which featured a dragon as large as Australia?

Comment: I agree with Daniel, it sounds like a 'space-bat-angel-dragon' the size of Australia to me.

Comment: Thankyou so much yes it was the iron man

Comment: See OP confirmation comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close off the question as per comments, it was *The Iron Man* by Ted Hughes.

Comment: A bare title is not an identification. There are half a dozen stories titled "The Iron Man".

Comment: @user14111 Only half a dozen?