# Story about a Giant Creature landing on earth?

Tags: story-identification

In the story people see a speck on the moon which keeps getting bigger day by day and eventually the creature lands on earth. I don't know if this is in the beginning or middle of the story. I read this excerpt about the landing in one of my old English Textbooks. The speck growing and landing is described in detail along with perception and thoughts of people. 
(This is not "Heresies of the Huge God", I read it to confirm that.)

**Update**: As per accepted answer, this and its possible duplicate question have same answer. But both questions are referring to different excerpts of same story. The excerpt I am referring to doesn't mention the robot. It is all about the appearance and arrival of the dragon.

Comment: Any chance you remember the name of the textbook, maybe what course it was for? When the story itself may have been published or when the textbook was published? Can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details?

Comment: Could be the second part of *The Iron Man*, previously mentioned [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180067/help-me-identify-this-novel-from-my-childhood#comment486735_180067).

Comment: @Shashwat, you're right, the questions are fundamentally different, but on this site when we have two accepted answers that are identifying the same story, we duplicate them to link them together. The difference in the excerpts means that a larger number of search terms will bring people looking for the story to the answer they seek. A duplicate is not a bad thing, and that's why you've still received 5 up-votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like *The Iron Man* also known as *The Iron Giant* by Ted Hughes.

A gigantic dragon the size of Australia lands on Earth and the Iron Man challenges it to a test to see if they can withstand fire.

The arrival of the dragon:

> In the middle of the giant star, a tiny black speck appeared. On the second
>   night this speck was seen to be wriggling, and much bigger. On the third night, you could see it without a telescope. A struggling black speck in the center of that giant, red, gloomy star.
>
> On the fifth night, the astronomers saw that it seemed to be either a bat, or a
>   black angel, or a flying lizard – a dreadful silhouette, flying out of the center of that
>   giant star, strait towards the earth. What was coming out of the giant star?
>
> Each night, when the astronomers returned to their telescopes to peer up, this
>   black flying horror was bigger. With slow, gigantic wingbeats, with long, slow
>   writhings of its body, it was coming down through space, outlined black against its
>   red star.
>
> Within a few more nights, its shape had completely blotted out the red star.
>   The nameless, immense bat-angel was flying down at the earth, like a great black
>   swan. It was definitely coming straight at the earth.
>
> It took several days to cover the distance.
>
> Then, for one awful night, its wings seemed to be filling most of the sky. The
>   moon peered fearfully from low on the skyline and all the people of earth stayed up,
>   gazing in fear at the huge black movement of wings that filled the night.
>
> Next morning it landed – on Australia.

Comment: Can you suggest any other details other than the Giant aspect that suggest similarity?

Comment: Well, it *gets bigger over time, before landing*; and it's the first think *I* thought of on reading that description too. I'm pretty sure I recall Hughes' work being used in an educational context on many occasions, too ...

Comment: This was the one. It is chapter 4 "The Space-Being and the Iron Man". We only had the excerpt till the dragon lands and looks over the world.